# How do I improve my thumbstick aiming?

Tags: controllers, first-person-shooter

I'm 99% a console gamer. My brain prefers that I have a controller in my hand. However, when a game requires that I use a thumbstick/control stick/analog stick to aim/target, I enter a world of frustration. So I usually stick with platformers.

When I do play games that require aiming/targeting with a thumb stick, seems I only have two speeds: extremely fast, shooting past the enemy, or creeping the enemy, never making it there. It gets even worse when I need to reposition the camera with the other thumb. I can feel the bad guys laughing at me. It's humiliating.

**How can I improve my thumb-stick aiming?** I'd like to expand the repertoire of games I enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Most shooters have aiming tied to camera rotation, adjust camera rotation/movement speed to your liking. If your aim moves extremely fast turn down the camera speed, and do the opposite if you move to slow. Repeat till you have found yourself a "sweet spot", so you can use it on other shooters too (often FPS and TPS have the same adjustment scale).

Gaming is for the biggest part skill based. Skill getting from experience, the more you game the better you come at it. If you play a lot of shooters, you will become more skillful at aiming in shooters.

Also: Turn off Auto-Aim!!! Sounds pretty stupid, but you won't learn aiming by yourself if you keep using AA. I'm even at a point where I can't play with AA anymore.